# Where can I get ILOG jars

Tags: ilog

Where can I get the below ILOG jars

1. jrules-engine.jar
2. jrules-res-XXXX-session-java.jar (XXXX - represent the version of the ILOG you are using)
3. jrules-res-execution.jar
4. jrules-res-session-XXXX.jar (XXXX - Represents the app server you are using websphere/weblogic etc..)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the jars specifically because ILOG is not an open source product from IBM,further more IBM has rebranded the product too as per the IBM's site

> JRules BRMS family has been enhanced with WebSphere Business Events,
>   bringing together two powerful decision automation technologies in a
>   single offering. This new product has been rebranded as IBM
>   Operational Decision Manager.

[So here is the place you can download the trial version](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/decision-management/operational-decision-management/websphere-operational-decision-management). After installing the trial version,you can get access to the jars that you have mentioned,but not the exact version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want integrate Intellirule editor in your application, there are an API witch you can integrate, you can recuperate this JARs in Teamserver Core.